# minikube start taking long time to downloading kubectl v1.17.2

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, minikube

I'm trying to start [Minikube](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/hello-minikube/) on my Windows machine and it looks hanging.
I downloaded `kubectl` and `minikube` as [Install kubectl](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-kubectl/) and [Install minikube](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-minikube/) articles says.

And when I run `minikube start` it shows this

```
PS C:\Users\1\.kube> minikube start
* minikube v1.7.2 on Microsoft Windows 10 Pro 10.0.16299 Build 16299
* Using the virtualbox driver based on existing profile
* Reconfiguring existing host ...
* Starting existing virtualbox VM for "minikube" ...
* Preparing Kubernetes v1.17.2 on Docker 19.03.5 ...
* Downloading kubeadm v1.17.2
* Downloading kubelet v1.17.2
* Downloading kubectl v1.17.2
```

And there is nothing happend after `Downloading kubectl v1.17.2` appeared for 10 minutes. 
Are kubectl still downloadiing and it so huge? And why it is downloading if kubectl was just installed?

I'm using Windows 10 Pro with Virtual Box 6.1 installed.

Comment: any proxys in your environment?

Comment: No proxies, moreover, I downloaded the kubectl.exe file manually via the direct link from the documentation and it did not take more than 10 seconds.

Comment: Is the issue still occuring? Did you try to download a new version of `minikube`?